# find_all elements in an array that match a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've an array of hash entries, and want to filter based on a paramater passed into the function.

If there are three values in the hash, `A`, `B`, and `C`, I want to do something similar to:

```
data = [{A:'a1', B:'b1', C:'c1'}, 
    {A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c1'},
    {A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c2'}, 
    {A:'a2', B:'b1', C:'c1'},
    {A:'a2', B:'b2', C:'c1'}]

data.find_all{ |d| d[:A].include?params[:A] }
    .find_all{ |d| d[:B].include?params[:B] }
    .find_all{ |d| d[:C].include?params[:C] }
```

find all where A == 'a1' AND B='b2'

so for above I get:
{A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c1'} and {A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c2'} 
* put `if` / `else` statements, like `params.has_key? 'B'` then do something.
* modify my code each time a new type of value is added to the Hash map (say now I have 'D').

Note: The key of the hash is a symbol, but the value is a string and I want to do a "contains" not "equals".

I think of it as SQL Select statement with where zero or more '==' clause

Comment: Do you really mean `C=1` throughout your pseudocode?

Comment: As `data` grows, your code is going to run more slowly. It'd be good to preprocess your array of hashes into something much more convenient, such as a single hash of arrays, like `data = { A:[ '1', '11', '13' ], B:[ '2', '21', '23' ], C:[ '3', '23', '33' ] }`, then you can use `data[:A].include?(params[:A])`, without having to loop over the array of hashes, which will speed things up somewhat.

Comment: I need to find the tuples that meet the clause, the recommended pre-processing will result in loss of info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then I believe that the `select` method of `Array` class may be helpful to you.

`select` takes a block of code which is intended to be a test condition on each element in your array.  Any elements within your array which satisfy that test condition will be *selected*, and the result is an array of those selected elements.

For example:

```
arr = [ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 ]
result = arr.select { |element| element > 20 }
puts result   # prints out [23, 42]
```

In your example, you have an array of hashes, which makes it only slightly more complicated than my example with a simple array of numbers.  In your example, we have:

```
data = [{A:'a1', B:'b1', C:'c1'}, 
        {A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c1'},
        {A:'a1', B:'b2', C:'c2'}, 
        {A:'a2', B:'b1', C:'c1'},
        {A:'a2', B:'b2', C:'c1'}]
```

I believe what you want your code to do is something like: *Select from my data array all of the hashes where, within the hash, `:A` equals some value AND `:B` equals some other value.*

Let's say you want to find all of the hashes where `:A == 'a1'` and `:B == 'b2'`.  You would do that like this:

```
data.select { |hash_element| hash_element[:A] == 'a1' && hash_element[:B] == 'b2' }
```

This line returns to you an array with those hashes from your original data array which satisfy the condition we provided in the block - that is, those hashes where `:A == 'a1'` and `:B == 'b2'`.  Hope that that helps shed some light on your problem!

More information about the `select` method here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select

**edited - below is an addition to original answer**

To follow up on your later question about `if/else` clauses and the addition of new parameters... the block of code that you pass to `select` can, of course, be much more complicated than what I've written in the example.  You just need to keep this in mind: *If the last line of the block of code evaluates to true, then the element will be selected into the result array.  Otherwise, it won't be selected.*

So, that means you could define a function of your own, and call that function within the condition block passed to `select`.  For example, something like this:

```
def condition_test(hash_element, key_values)
    result = true
    key_values.each do |pair|
      if hash_element[pair[:key]] != pair[:value]
        result = false
      end
    end
    return result
end

# An example of the key-value pairs you might require to satisfy your select condition.
requirements = [ {:key => :A, :value => 'a1'},
                 {:key => :B, :value => 'b2'} ]

data.select { |hash_element| condition_test(hash_element, requirements) }
```

This makes your condition block a bit more dynamic, rather than hard-wired for `:A == 'a1'` and `:B == 'b2'` like we did in the earlier example.  You can tweak `requirements` on the fly based on the keys and values that you need to look for.  You could also modify `condition_test` to do more than just check to see if the hash value at some key equals some value.  You can add in your `if/else` clauses in `condition_test` to test for things like the presence of some key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use .values_at(key)

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at[values_at method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)